# Flaws showing $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z})/\left<(3,3,3)\right> \simeq \mathbb{Z_{3}}\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Now I know that $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z})/\left<(3,3,3)\right> \simeq \mathbb{Z_{3}}\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ by fundamental theorem of homomorphism. But why is the following wrong:

\begin{align*}
(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z})/\left<(3,3,3)\right> 
&= \{(a,b,c)+\left<(3,3,3)\right> \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}\} \\ 
&= \{(a,b,c) + \{3\mathbb{Z}\} \times \{3\mathbb{Z}\} \times \{3\mathbb{Z}\} \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}\}  \\
&= \{ \{a+3\mathbb{Z}\}+\{b+3\mathbb{Z}\}+\{c+3\mathbb{Z}\} \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}\}.\end{align*}

Thus any element can be uniquely written in the form of $(l,m,n) + \langle (3, 3, 3) \rangle$ where $l,m,n \in \mathbb{Z_{3}}$. Therefore the factor group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{3}} \times \mathbb{Z_{3}} \times \mathbb{Z_{3}}$. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I hope my edit did not interfere with yours -- I tried to be mindful of what you'd added!

Comment: What comes after the second equals sign is simply incorrect.

Comment: @pjs36 no problem!

Comment: The first line of your third paragraph is false. Try writing $(17,17,3)$ as equivalent to something like $(l,m,n)$ with $0\leq l,m,n<3$ modulo elements of the form $(3k,3k,3k)$ and you'll see what's going wrong.

Comment: For example, $(3,6,9)\in 3\mathbb Z\times3\mathbb Z\times3\mathbb Z$, but this is not a multiple of $(3,3,3)$.

Comment: @MattSamuel oh thanks!